# C - What did I do wrong to make it output 32764 instead of 4

Tags: c

So I tried to write a simple calculator in C and the output number is wrong.
For example if I input 1 (to select addition) and do 2 + 2 it outputs 32765

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char userInput;
    char Add = "1", Subtract = "2", Multiply = "3", Divide = "4";
    int num, num1, num2;
    printf("\n----------------");
    printf("\n(1) - Add       ");
    printf("\n(2) - Subtract  ");
    printf("\n(3) - Multiply  ");
    printf("\n(4) - Subtract  ");
    printf("\n----------------");

    printf("\nEnter a number to indicate which one you want to select\n>  ");
    scanf("%d", &userInput);
    
    printf("\nEnter the first number\n>  ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    
    printf("\nEnter the second number\n>  ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    if (userInput == Add       ) { num = num1 + num2; }
    if (userInput == Subtract  ) { num = num1 - num2; }
    if (userInput == Multiply  ) { num = num1 * num2; }
    if (userInput == Divide    ) { num = num1 / num2; }

    printf("\nYour output is: %d\n\n", num);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char Add = "1"` - this is wrong. `"1"` is a pointer to a string containig `'1'` and a null character. And then you read a *number* and compare to it.

Comment: Does the program compile without warnings or errors?

Comment: If you want `char`, you want `'c'`, not `"c"`.

Comment: That does not compile without warnings.

Comment: Paul Hankin. i get some errors with the if statements https://pastebin.com/DKrTQpiW Edit: after changing the "1" "2" etc the warnings were gone

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and read the warnings. This yields 5 warnings for me.

Comment: Both clang and gcc give 5 warnings, all of which happen to be fatal to the correctness of the program. After fixing compiler warnings, the next step would be to single-step through the code (or add print statements) to check the values of variables as the program executes.

Comment: @Martin don't post links, but [edit] your question and put all relevant information _there_

Comment: You should use `else if` and print an error if none of the choices are true.

Comment: _makes integer from pointer without a cast_: this warning is actually almost always an error rather than a warning.

Comment: @Ben sorry, forget it, I edited my comment (and just upvoted your answer). You can delete your comment, I'll delete this one too

Comment: @stark i added and if else statement with else at the end to tell if none were selected and none were selected

Comment: Some advise: "Why does this code think (something wrong)" is not the best mindset to have when programming. "What mistake or wrong assumption did I make that causes the program to fail" is better.

Comment: @PaulHankin understood

Answer (score 1):

Everything there should just be "int":

```
int main()
{
    int userInput;
    int Add = 1, Subtract = 2, Multiply = 3, Divide = 4;
    int num, num1, num2;
    scanf("%d", &userInput);
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    if (userInput == Add       ) { num = num1 + num2; }
    if (userInput == Subtract  ) { num = num1 - num2; }
    if (userInput == Multiply  ) { num = num1 * num2; }
    if (userInput == Divide    ) { num = num1 / num2; }
    
    printf("\nYour output is: %d\n\n", num);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Then it works fine:

```
$ cc v.c
$ ./a.out 

----------------
(1) - Add       
(2) - Subtract  
(3) - Multiply  
(4) - Subtract  
----------------
Enter a number to indicate wich one you want to select
>  1

Enter the first number
>  2

Enter the second number
>  3

Your output is: 5
```

Compiler should have warned you about this.

Comment: ty. im new to c so im bad at this.    Now it works :)